# Borland C++Builder recompile project with components in a package

Tags: c++builder-5

I have a project in Borland C++Builder 5.

The project contains some components.

I am changing component code, rebuilding the package and installing it, then running the main program (which uses the components).

The problem is that the old component code is executed. Is there some other rebuild function I am missing?

I have tried deleting the package and reinstalling it, but no success. Still the old code is executed.

When I delete the `bpi` and `lib` files by hand, everything works. Is there a faster work path?

Comment: Old IDE versions did not provide much in the way of project management, especially when it comes to cleaning a project before re-compiling it. You might try creating a `.bat` script to delete old files (not just `.bpi` and `.lib`, but also `.obj`), and then run that before compiling.

Comment: You should unload from the IDE the component package in order to update it; I do not see that phase.
Furthermore, if you do not do it, it should be impossible to actually update (relink) the `.bpl` while used by the IDE, Windows won't allow that; hence you probably had that `.bpl` duplicated of sorts, and the `.bpl` you are updating is not the one which is loaded in the IDE; so you keep seeing the old version...